# Dark/Light mode button to toggle colours in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

Im using a lavalamp javascript effect for a background. I Have also implemented a dark/light mode toggle with CSS media query. The toggle works as expected, switching the colour theme but not the javascript lavalamp colours. Would this be handled in the javascript or in the CSS?

The desired effect would allow lavalamp colours also toggle and be set by the dark mode media query.

**https://codepen.io/cleaton/pen/NWJMyGG**

[image: Light mode]

[image: Dark mode]

```
    // Colour mode controls
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
if (currentTheme == "dark") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
} else if (currentTheme == "light") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (prefersDarkScheme.matches) {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("light-theme")
      ? "light"
      : "dark";
  } else {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")
      ? "dark"
      : "light";
  }
  localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
});

// Create a PixiJS application of type cavas with specify background color and make it resizes to the iframe window
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  background: "yellow",
  resizeTo: window
});

// Adding the application's view to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// Basic settings
app.stage.eventMode = "dynamic";
app.stage.hitArea = app.screen;

// Create container for orbs
const container = new PIXI.Container();
app.stage.addChild(container);

// Make a nice color pallete for our random orbs
const colors = ["0x4361ee", "0x3a0ca3", "0x7209b7", "0xf72585"];
const blurFilter2 = new PIXI.BlurFilter();

// Helper Functions

function randomCircle() {
  const circle = new PIXI.Graphics();
  // create random circle
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  circle.beginFill(colors[randomColor]);
  circle.drawCircle(0, 0, (Math.random() * app.screen.width) / 4);
  circle.endFill();
  // generateTexture converts a graphic to a texture, which can be used to
  // create a sprite
  const texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(circle);
  return {
    texture
  };
}

// Orbs
const orbs = [];

// orb vars
let trackSpeed = 0.03;
let rotationSpeed = 0.01;

// set wrapping boundaries (invisible rectangle) to be roughly equal to orb size
const padding = app.screen.width / 4;
const bounds = new PIXI.Rectangle(
  -padding,
  -padding,
  app.screen.width + padding * 2,
  app.screen.height + padding * 2
);

// create 20 orbs with randomized variables
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  const orb = PIXI.Sprite.from(randomCircle().texture);

  orb.anchor.set(0.5);
  container.addChild(orb);

  orb.direction = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  orb.speed = 1;
  orb.turnSpeed = Math.random() - 0.8;

  orb.x = Math.random() * bounds.width;
  orb.y = Math.random() * bounds.height;

  orb.scale.set(1 + Math.random() * 0.3);
  orb.original = new PIXI.Point();
  orb.original.copyFrom(orb.scale);

  orbs.push(orb);
}

// Blur the orbs
// This seems like it could get pretty heavy pretty fast, low quality is fast but not very smooth
container.filters = [blurFilter2];
blurFilter2.blur = 300;
blurFilter2.quality = 35;

// Events
// store cursor coords
let mouseX;
let mouseY;

app.stage.on("pointermove", (event) => {
  mouseX = event.global.x;
  mouseY = event.global.y;
});

// Ticker variables
let count = 0;

// Listen for animate update
app.ticker.add((delta) => {
  count += 0.02;

  // animate orbs
  for (let i = 0; i < orbs.length; i++) {
    const orb = orbs[i];

    orb.direction += orb.turnSpeed * 0.01;
    orb.x += Math.sin(orb.direction) * orb.speed;
    orb.y += Math.cos(orb.direction) * orb.speed;

    orb.rotation = -orb.direction - Math.PI / 2;
    orb.scale.x = orb.original.x + Math.sin(count) * 0.2;

    // wrap the orbs around as they hit the bounds
    if (orb.x < bounds.x) {
      orb.x += bounds.width;
    } else if (orb.x > bounds.x + bounds.width) {
      orb.x -= bounds.width;
    }

    if (orb.y < bounds.y) {
      orb.y += bounds.height;
    } else if (orb.y > bounds.y + bounds.height) {
      orb.y -= bounds.height;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You'll need to remove those Graphics, redraw them with new color array. Since your code isn't reusable, it's quite a lot of work to give you a demo.

Comment: Alternatively could the toggle switch JS files? Two files with the different colour themes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by switch JS files. But when something is drawn on a canvas, it's hard to change anything on it, 9/10 its a matter of remove and redraw with your updated things.

Comment: I mean, if it displayed the lava effect relative to the users light/dark theme setting (lava-light.js). Then the toggle would act similar to current and switch the CSS colours but also the javascript file (lava-dark.js).

Comment: Yea thats possible, but did you ever read about the DRY principle? It's probably a lot better to spend a little more time to be able to call a function that draws those things, so you can remove the app and call that functin again if the theme changes.

Comment: I've not heard for the DRY principle but thats certainly the direction I would be interested in taking it but limited by my skills

Answer (score 3):

From a quick test, the [CSS `filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) appears to work on `<canvas>` elements.

In your codepen example, you would add the following:

```css
body.dark-theme canvas {
  filter: saturate(0);
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body.light-theme canvas {
    filter: saturate(1);
  }
}
```

**but...** there's a got'cha: the z-index of the canvas changes when applying the filter. Adding `position: absolute;` and `z-index: -1;` will prevent  the canvas from covering the page.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comments into an answer.

Drawing on a canvas makes it quite hard to alter the colors, you'll need to

- Draw Orbs
- On button click;

  - Remove the orbs
  - Draw them with correct colors

---

Since you've already placed all the orbs in a `container`, we can remove the orbs with the following method:

```
container.removeChildren();
```

<sup>[[docs]](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html#removeChildren)</sup>

---

Then, call the draw logic again, I've moved that to a seperate function `addOrbs` which calls `randomCircle` as you made, but I've added a `darkColors` array which is chosen over the `colors` array if `theme === 'dark'`.

I've removed the animation for this demo to reduce the amount of code.

Some parts could also still be optimised, but this is just to share the idea.

Hope it helps.

```js
let   theme = 'light';
const toggleTheme = () => (theme = (theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'));
const colors = ["0x4361ee", "0x3a0ca3", "0x7209b7", "0xf72585"];
const darkColors = ["0x221D00", "0x423800", "0x22001D", "0x22001d"];

const app = new PIXI.Application({
    background: "yellow",
    resizeTo: document.window
});

const padding = app.screen.width / 4;
const bounds = new PIXI.Rectangle(
  -padding,
  -padding,
  app.screen.width + padding * 2,
  app.screen.height + padding * 2
);

const container = new PIXI.Container();
app.stage.addChild(container);
document.body.appendChild(app.view);   

function randomCircle() {
  const circle = new PIXI.Graphics();
  const availableColors = (theme === 'dark') ? darkColors : colors;
  // create random circle
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableColors.length);
  circle.beginFill(availableColors[randomColor]);
  circle.drawCircle(0, 0, (Math.random() * app.screen.width) / 4);
  circle.endFill();
  // generateTexture converts a graphic to a texture, which can be used to
  // create a sprite
  const texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(circle);
  return {
    texture
  };
}

const addOrbs = (dark = false) => {
        
    app.stage.eventMode = "dynamic";
    app.stage.hitArea = app.screen;
       
    const blurFilter2 = new PIXI.BlurFilter();
    
    const orbs = [];
    let trackSpeed = 0.03;
    let rotationSpeed = 0.01;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      const orb = PIXI.Sprite.from(randomCircle().texture);

      orb.anchor.set(0.5);
      container.addChild(orb);

      orb.direction = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
      orb.speed = 1;
      orb.turnSpeed = Math.random() - 0.8;

      orb.x = Math.random() * bounds.width;
      orb.y = Math.random() * bounds.height;

      orb.scale.set(1 + Math.random() * 0.3);
      orb.original = new PIXI.Point();
      orb.original.copyFrom(orb.scale);

      orbs.push(orb);
    }
}

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-toggle');
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  toggleTheme();
  container.removeChildren();
  addOrbs();
});

addOrbs();
```

```css
.content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


body {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;
}
body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}

body, .content {
  background: var(--bkg-color);
}

h1, p {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/7.2.4/pixi.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's very insightful along with your other comments. Thank you for sharing

Comment: Glad it helped, also the other comments. The DRY principe is always a good think to keep in your mind, will save you a lot of work later on. Thanks for your comment/vote, that makes the work worth it ;)